# write all functions as rational functions

Tags: functions, polynomials, control-theory

my question is short and simple : could we write all functions that have the formula : $1 + G(s)H(s)$ as

$$\frac{(s+b_0)(s+b_1)\dots(s+b_n)}{(s+p_0)\dots(s+p_m)}$$

if the answer is yes , could you proof it ?
B.S : this formula is famouse in control theory or control systems .

Comment: ...and then we use our increidible mental powers and *guess* what in the world is G(s), H(s), B0 and etc.....

Comment: @DonAntonio , i do not understand !

Comment: you and I both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, because $G(s)$ and $H(s)$ are both rational polynomials. Let $G(s)=N_G(s) / D_G(s)$ and $H(s)=N_H(s) / D_H(s)$ where $N_G(s)$, $D_G(s)$, $N_H(s)$ and $D_H(s)$ are polynomials. Then,

$$1 + G(s) H(s) = \frac{D_G(s) D_H(s) + N_G(s) N_H(s)}{D_G(s) D_H(s)} $$